# MVC ASP.NET5 Project Template Memory Leak

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks

Using MS Visual Studio 2015 RC

Load the template project, keep hitting the Contact link, watch the Private Bytes memory usage increase on every single click until you reach an out of memory exception. Exception happens in both debug and release mode.

First observed in my own project, so stripped right back to the template project and still observe the same behaviour.

I have also created the same base project using ASP.NET 4.6 Template for MVC and doing the same in that project raises memory usage a little and then levels out as you would expect - it does not increase ad infinitum.

Is memory allocation an issue in ASP.NET 5 as it stands?

Can anyone provide any insight? Has anyone else experienced / worked around the same issue?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Sorry - just added the Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Browser Link causes memory growth (as you want to keep that information around).

Try removing the line from `Startup.cs`: `app.UseBrowserLink();`